# Creating recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

Initially this seemed like a no brainer, but the more I am trying to do this, the more I am getting stuck.

I am looking to create a recursive method that will take a string and output combination with dots as below:

input: test

output:

```
test
t.est
te.st
tes.t
t.es.t
te.s.t
t.e.s.t
t.e.st
```

you get the idea... I need all permutations of dots between the characters. But two dots should not appear together and dot should not be the first or the last character.

The code I have written is:

```
public final class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      recurse ("test");
   }

   public static void recurse(String str){
        recurse("",str);
   }

   public static void recurse (String pre, String str){
      if(str.length() > 1){
         recurse(pre+str.substring(0,1)+".",str.substring(1));
      }
      System.out.println(pre+str);  
   }
}
```

But, I can't get my head around it. What change should I do?

Just for the sake of clarification I got the idea from https://medium.com/@JakeCooper/so-nice-i-did-it-twice-hacking-the-oneplus-reservation-system-again-2e8226c45f9a, but I do not have any intention of hacking the invite system.

Comment: @ka4eli When `str.length() <= 1` .

Comment: do you want to do this as part of `oneplus2` invite hack? :P

Comment: Hehe, @ReservoirSampling, I did get the idea from the post in medium, but I have no intention of purchasing OnePlus 2, or hacking its invite system (wouldn't touch that phone with a 10 foot pole). I just wanted to do the same string manipulation in java as a way of passing time, like I said, seemed a no-brainer and then I got stuck! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
public static void recurse(String prev, String next) {
    if (next.length() == 0) 
        System.out.println(prev);
    else {
        recurse(prev + next.charAt(0), next.substring(1));
        recurse(prev + "." + next.charAt(0), next.substring(1));
    }    
}
```

If you allow `.` to precede the entire String as well, use:

```
String s = "test";
recurse("",s);
```

If you don't allow `.` to precede:

```
recurse(s.charAt(0), s.substring(1));
```

If you allow `.` to be appended (i.e. `test.` , `t.e.s.t.`), change the if block to

```
if (next.length() == 0) {
    System.out.println(prev);
    System.out.println(prev + ".");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is what I was expecting my code to be. But I was missing the 2nd recurse call.

Answer (score 2):

I would pass the position in the string to the recurse function :

```
public static void recurse(String str) {
    recurse(str, 1); // start only at 1 since we do not want dot at first position
}

public static void recurse(String str, int n) {
    if (n >= str.length()) { // >= since no dot at last position
        System.out.println(str); // ok we have a full string : print it
    } else {
        recurse(str, n + 1);    // either not dot and recurse
        str = str.substring(0, n) + "." + str.substring(n); // or add one at n
        recurse(str, n + 2);   // and recurse too
    }
}
```

The output of `recurse("test")` is as expected :

```
test
tes.t
te.st
te.s.t
t.est
t.es.t
t.e.st
t.e.s.t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this works quite well. Actually, what I wanted to know was what was wrong in my approach. This could have been done in many ways, but I chose one and I couldn't complete the thing with that, hence I was interested in knowing what was missing from my code!

Answer (score 1):

You might use the following piece of code:

```
public static void recurse (String pre, String str){
    if(str.length() > 1) {
        String str1 = pre + str.substring(0,1) + ".";
        String str2 = str.substring(1);
        System.out.println(pre + str);
        recurse(str1, str2);
    }
    System.out.println(pre + str);
}
```

Output:

```
test
t.est
t.e.st
t.e.s.t
t.e.st
t.est
test
```

Comment: As you can see in the output and code, you are printing each string twice. Which may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Updated the question with required output. Basically I want all permutations of dots between the characters

Comment: @inquizitive, i don't understand your algorithm

Comment: @inquizitive, `te.s.t` -> `t.e.s.t` -> `t.e.st` Explain me this sequence

Comment: There is no sequence in the question, I have just tried to show all combinations possible with `test`. The sequence is not important.

Comment: @inquizitive, recursion must have algorithm, otherwise it isn't recursion

Answer (score 1):

You need to recurse in a loop to get all possibilities.

```
public static void recurse(String pre, String str) {
    pre += ".";
    System.out.println(pre + str);
    for (int i = 1; i <= str.length(); i++)
        recurse(pre + str.substring(0, i), str.substring(i));
}
```

Output:

```
.tes
.t.es
.t.e.s
.t.e.s.
.t.es.
.te.s
.te.s.
.tes.
```

Note: You may need to modify this a little to not include the `.` at the beginning.

Comment: Won't this be stuck infinitely calling `recurse()`? The beginning of each loop calls `recurse()` which starts another loop which calls `recurse()` and so on until the computer complains about having too many functions in the stack. The recursive nature of this problem means you _don't_ want a loop, or at least not one that calls the function inside of it with no way to escape.

Comment: Thanks, this works, and you have probably the closest answer to what I was looking for since I wanted to know what needed to be added to the code I HAD ALREADY written. Oh.. and I added `if(!pre.isEmpty()) pre += ".";` for the initial dot!

Comment: @Will, the condition in the loop will stop the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to append a new character to `pre` for each recursive call by taking the first character from `str`, so you should stop when only one character is left in `str`.

```
public static void recurse(String pre, String str) {
    if (str.length() == 1) {
        System.out.println(pre + str);
        System.out.println(pre + " ." + str);
        return;
    }

    recurse(pre + str.substring(0, 1), str.substring(1));
    if (pre.length() > 0)
        recurse(pre + "." + str.substring(0, 1), str.substring(1));
}
```

Calling it with `recurse("", "test");` gives you:

```
test
tes .t
te.st
te.s .t
t.est
t.es .t
t.e.st
t.e.s .t
```